derivatives of Frobenius norm with respect to complex matrix
I encountered a math problem when reading some optimization papers. In one of the paper, it minimize a function of Frobenius norm of complex matrices:
$\min_{U} \frac{\beta}{2}\mathrm{\left\| H-UV_{}^{H} \right\|}_{F}^{2}+\frac{\mu}{2}\sum_{r=1}^{R}\mathrm{\left\| RQ_{r}U-C \right\|}_{F}^{2}$
where all metric are complex, $Q_{r}$ is an operator which takes the r-th column of a matrix, and R is an Hankel operator, which maps a vector to a Hankel matrix.
The paper says the solution to the above optimization is:
$\mu\sum_{r=1}^{R}Q_{r}^{*}R_{}^{*}RQU+\beta UV_{}^{H}conj(V)=\sum_{r=1}^{R}\mu Q_{r}^{*}R_{}^{*}C+\beta Hconj(V)$
where $R_{}^{*}$ is the adjoint Hankel operator, and $Q_{r}^{*}$ is the adjoint $Q_{r}$ operator.
I understand the general steps of solving the minimization problem by calculate the derivative of the two Frobenius norms, and set the derivative to zero. However,I don't understand how the adjoint operators are derived from the equation.
your help is appreciated.
